# How do i override a dependency property set in XAML to the value i need to in codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I have a dependency property RecordContainerGenerationMode defined for XamDatagrid , irrespective of what the user sets in the XAML i need it to default to a specific value PreLoad .

How do i accomplish this ? The Xamdatagrid is a infragistics grid which  really allow me to hide the dependency  implementation.

I tried setting the value in the constructor of the xamdatagrid but the XAML defined value is overwritten onto it.

```
<Controls:XamDataGrid Grid.Row="1"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  x:Name="gridTrdDetail"
                  DataSource="{Binding Items}"
                  SelectedRecords="{Binding SelectedObjects, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  IncludeDefaultCommands="True"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  ScrollingMode="Immediate" 
                  CellContainerGenerationMode="Recycle"
                  GroupByAreaMode="MultipleFieldLayoutsCompact"
                  RecordContainerGenerationMode="PreLoad" SelectedSum="{Binding Sum,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
```

and this is how i set it in constructor : -

```
public XamDataGrid()
    {
      this.SetValue(XamDataGrid.RecordContainerGenerationModeProperty,ItemContainerGenerationMode.PreLoad);            
    }
```

Has anyone run into this kinda issue anywhere?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by that? Looks like a *code smell*..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to do something like that.  Like Anatolii Gabuza said, definite code smell there. It's something you'll need to really rethink.

The way everything gets generated is the control gets constructed (calling default constructor), then the properties in XAML get assigned, then if there are data bindings, the value gets updated at run time.

If you don't want the value to change, the easiest way is just don't expose it!  If you need to read the value, maybe you can try a read only dependency property.

If you REALLY want it to expose the Dependency Property, you can set it in the property changed event.  But, that kind of defeats the purpose of having a dependency property in the first place.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RecordContainerGenerationModeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "RecordContainerGenerationMode", 
    typeof(ItemContainerGenerationMode), 
    typeof(XamDataGrid), 
    new PropertyMetadata(ItemContainerGenerationMode.PreLoad, OnRecordContainerGenerationModeChanged));


private static void OnRecordContainerGenerationModeChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    XamDataGrid control = obj as XamDataGrid;

    if (control != null)
    {
        ItemContainerGenerationMode newMode = (ItemContainerGenerationMode)args.NewValue;

        if (newMode != ItemContainerGenerationMode.PreLoad)
        {
            control.RecordContainerGenerationMode = ItemContainerGenerationMode.PreLoad;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a third party control by infragistics so I m stuck with being unable to hide that dependency property else that would have been my approach.

Comment: Why do you even need to hide it in the first place?  Even if you do create an inherited version of that control, what's stopping someone from using the original XamDataGrid that has that property exposed?

Comment: Even i inherit the grid i dont think i can hide a already existing dependency property and hence i was looking at this approach , i m open to new ideas if you think this idea is not correct .

Comment: One thing you can do is just create a wrapper control and only expose the properties you want to expose.